# WebKitBrowser.StringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString returns no value

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I need to get html after all javascripts run.I use WebKit.NET for it and the problem is that WebKitBrowser.StringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString doesn't return anything even with simple alert().And when I pass "document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML" (it is actually what I need to get) as the argument it throws the System.AccessViolationException(Attempted to read or write protected memory). And of course I do call StringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString in the function that is stick to the DocumentCompleted delegate.I've tried to do the same with WebView in objective-c with the same function StringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString and with the same argument "document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML" and it works good as well as it works good with "document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML" in console of the browser. Please help or maybe give alternatives how can I get whole html after runnig all javascripts.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();          
        webKitBrowser1.Navigate("http://famous-design.ru/stoly/");

        webKitBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webKitBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;

    }


    void webKitBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        string str = webKitBrowser1.StringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML");

    }
```

Comment: why use: document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0] when you could use: document.documentElement

Answer (score 1):

What i do is i integrate  `webKitBrowser1.StringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` with `webKitBrowser1.Document.InvokeScriptMethod` :

So you have this:

```
webKitBrowser1.StringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString("function GetElement() {document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML};")
var returnvalue = (string) webKitBrowser1.Document.InvokeScriptMethod("GetElement");
```

where the return value is `returnvalue` in the code with the object string (Of course you can change it)

Answer (score 0):

I got that error too, I tried changing html to body like this:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].outerHTML
```

Then it worked.